# Capacity Constraint Check only at node level in OR-Tools

Tags: python-3.x, or-tools, operations-research

We have combined the pickup delivery module with capacity constraint. Here, we keep on picking up and dropping the items on the route (there can be pickup and drop on the same node). Hence, a person will be able to take more orders even though his capacity is less, because, at next node he will be dropping it.

E.g:
Let's assume:

```
Vehicle capacity is 10 kg. 
Total nodes = 11 (0 to 10)
Pickup Nodes: 1, 3, 8, 10
Drop Nodes: 5, 2, 4
```

we have maintained two arrays " **data['pickup_demand']** " is for demands at pickup nodes and " **data['delivery_demand']** " demand at drop nods. We are also subtracting it as to get the final data  **( i.e: " data['demands'] = data['pickup_demand'] - data['delivery_demand'] ")**.

```
    data['pickup_demand'] = [0, 8, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 6]
    data['delivery_demand'] = [0, 0, 6, 10, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    
Expected Routing:-
               0(0) -> 1(8) -> 3(2) -> 5(5) -> 8(5) -> 2(6) -> 10(6) -> 3(10) -> 0(0)
                 |       |       |       |       |       |        |        |       |
                Depot  Pickup  Pickup   Drop   Pickup   Drop    Pickup   Drop    Depot
```

Here, if we see, the same vehicle is able to this total task even though it's max. weight is **10 kg**.

We do not want to consider what is it's total weight (ie. adding all the pickups here, it is **21 kg**) it has carried for all the orders. But, the check should be only on node basis, which, should not be greater than 10 kg. In this way the vehicle does more task.

Even though the routing is not like the shown above, but, our requirement is to consider max. weight check on the node only.

I think, I need to modify this?

```
routing.AddDimensionWithVehicleCapacity(
        demand_callback_index,
        0,  # null capacity slack
        data['vehicle_capacities'],  # vehicle maximum capacities
        True,  # start cumul to zero
        'Capacity')
```

Comment: already answered on the mailing list, you need to duplicate the node which are pickup and delivery and adapt the callback (i.e. your matrix cost) accordingly...

Comment: Yes, @Mizux. I am working on the changes.